# vmrun clone "The snapshot already exists"

Tags: clone, snapshot, vmware-workstation, vmrun

I am trying to use the vmrun command line utility to clone the VM on workstation that is currently powered off.

I am using the following command using vmrun --help:

`$> *vmrun -T ws "path-to-the-.vmx-file-of-the-vm-that-needsto-be-cloned" "path-to-the-    directory-where-the-cloned-vm-should-be-created" full -cloneName=NameOfTheClonedVM*`

I keep getting the following error:

`Error: The Snapshot already exists`

Am I missing something here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be very old, but I happened to run into this issue - and find the answer - this evening.  The help file means exactly what it says:

> vmrun clone "Path to vmx file" "Path to destination vmx file" full|linked [-snapshot=Snapshot Name] [-cloneName=Name]

Like me on my initial attempt, you appear to be only specifying the paths rather than the vmx files.

Try this:

```
vmrun -T ws clone \path\sourcefile.vmx \path\targetfile.vmx full -cloneName=NameOfTheClonedVM
```

Updated to add the 'clone' directive in the syntax.  Note that for this to work, the VM must be powered-down or the optional snapshot directive must be specified and pointed at a snap of the VM in a powered-down state.  With the snapshot directive, it would look something like this:

```
vmrun -T ws clone \path\sourcefile.vmx \path\targetfile.vmx full -snapshot=snapshot2clone -cloneName=NameOfTheClonedVM
```

Comment: So I ran into this problem again tonight and found my own answer, which I only remembered posting on reading it again. Unfortunately, my original syntax was missing the 'clone' directive as well as the optional snapshot designator.  I've edited the post to reflect correct/better syntax.